# Is there a way for a console application to fully release the console it was launched from?

Tags: windows, winapi, console-application

I have a Windows console application written in C/C++.
I want, eventually (depending on X condition), to completely release the console my App was launched from and stop the console from waiting for my App to finish (so the user can keep using the console as usual).
Kind of, if X happens then return the console control to the user and keep running in the background. Is it possible?

I tried calling [FreeConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole) but it seems like the console keeps waiting for my program to finish. Maybe I'm missing something like closing std I/O handlers or another step.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Kind of, if X happens then return the console control to the user and keep running in the background. Is it possible?

Not that I'm aware of, no.  Once a new console process begins running, it is attached to the console that launched it and remains attached until it exits.  There is no API (that I know of) to break that attachment for a console process.

You will likely have to make your console app spawn a new non-console process for its remaining background work, and then exit from the original process.

Or, you could do all of your work in a background service app to begin with, and have your console app simply communicate with it via an IPC mechanism when needed.

Comment: It's also possible to fake being a console program. Mark it GUI instead then use WMI to examine the launching process. If that launching process is a console program attach to it and proceed. There is plenty of info out there about how to attach the runtime library standard streams to an existing console. I've used this in the past to determine where to send program usage info, if launched from a console it prints there, otherwise it uses a message box.